# Snowfire/Beautymail Laravel unable to push data into subject and view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im using this package for laravel: Snowfire/Beautymail and I am trying to push data into the subject of $message however I keep getting that this variable doesn't exist and I cant work out how to fix it.
Here is a look at my function:

```
$name = (DB::table('base_projects_databases')->select('name')->where('id','=', $request->projectID)->get())[0]->name;

$beautymail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
$beautymail->send('emails.newIssue', ["project" => $name], function($message)
{
  $message
  ->from('notifier@yetanotherissuetracker.com')
  ->to('admin@yetanotherissuetracker.com', 'Dan Marks')
  ->subject('New Issue Created For: ' . $project);
});
```

I also want to get data into the view but i cant work out how to do that either. 
Thanks

Comment: how you are passing $project variable to your controller? with request? can you post your route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$project` doesn't exist in the function scope, you need to add a `use` to the function to be able to use the variable in this scope.

Like so:

```
$name = (DB::table('base_projects_databases')->select('name')->where('id','=', $request->projectID)->get())[0]->name;

$beautymail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
$beautymail->send('emails.newIssue', ["project" => $name], function($message) use($name)
{
  $message
  ->from('notifier@yetanotherissuetracker.com')
  ->to('admin@yetanotherissuetracker.com', 'Dan Marks')
  ->subject('New Issue Created For: ' . $name);
});
```

For multiple variables you can comma separate the variables: `use($var1, $var2)`.

Comment: Ok so how would I add that in then?

Comment: As I did in the example, add `use($name)` or any other variable after the anonymous function.

Comment: Happy I could help, don't forget to accept this answer as the solution. :)

Comment: Thank you. I got idea from this answer.

Comment: I can not use  or dispaly $name variable  at  email view page how i solve this